# Could not find a part of the path . Update sql using upload buttom

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

if i choose photo or image with FileUpload control .. The Record Update procees will success but if the FileUpload Control Has no file choosen  The Above Error Appear , to keep in mind the path is correct and exists and the FileUpload Control Saves The Picture Without any problem .

```
protected SqlCommand News_command;
protected SqlDataAdapter News_adp;
protected System.Data.DataTable News_tbl;
protected SqlConnection _connection;
protected string _ID;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if ((Request.QueryString["ID"] != null))
    {
        _ID = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
    }

    prepareConnection();
    News_command.CommandText = "select * from News where ID=@ID";
    News_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", _ID);
    News_adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
    News_tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
    News_adp.SelectCommand = News_command;
    News_adp.Fill(News_tbl);


    if (News_tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        lblID.Text = News_tbl.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
        titleTextBox.Text = News_tbl.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
        CKEditor1.Text = News_tbl.Rows[0]["Contect"].ToString();
        imgArticle.ImageUrl = News_tbl.Rows[0]["img"].ToString();
        lblDate.Text = News_tbl.Rows[0]["Date"].ToString();
    }
}

protected void prepareConnection()
{
    _connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Abu-Adam\localhost;Initial Catalog=BrainStorms;User ID=sa;Password=ameer123");
    _connection.Open();
    News_command = new SqlCommand();
    News_command.Connection = _connection;
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile == null)
    {
        prepareConnection();
        News_command.CommandText = "UPDATE News SET Title=" + "N'" + titleTextBox.Text + "'" + "," + "Contect=" + "N'" + CKEditor1.Text + "'" + " WHERE ID='" + Convert.ToInt16(lblID.Text) + "';";
        News_command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }

    else if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
    {
        prepareConnection();
        string FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        //save file to disk

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ArticleImages/News/" + FileName));
        News_command.CommandText = "UPDATE News SET Title=" + "N'" + titleTextBox.Text + "'" + "," + "Contect=" + "N'" + CKEditor1.Text + "'" + ",img=@FilePath WHERE ID='" + Convert.ToInt16(lblID.Text) + "';";
        News_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FilePath", "~/ArticleImages/News/" + FileName);
        try
        {
            News_command.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            News_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

where is the wrong in my code ?? any suggestion please ??

regards 
Ameer.

Comment: I Solved it 

replacing if (FileUpload1.PostedFile !=null) with if (FileUpload1.HasFile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because as per your code Fileupload never comes null.
Try validating your code:

```
if(fileUpload.HasFile && fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength>0) // check for 
                                                                 validity of file
{
  var path = string.Format("~/YourImageDir/{0}",Guid.NewGuid().ToString().
  Replace("-",string.Empty));     
  //then do your update with this above path 
}
else
{
 // update without file path
}
```

Comment: Thank u Amit .. This Could Help in the near Future =]